# javascript how to call a function inside function

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript

```
(function (document, window, $) {
    'use strict';

    var Site = window.Site;

    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        Site.run();
        var $this = this;

        // Init function
        // ------------------------
        (function () {

            function init() {

                $('tr[data-toggle="slidePanel"]').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var me = $(this);

                .... some code here
            }

            init();

        })();

        // Employee function
        // ------------------------
        (function () {

            function getData() {

                ... some code here

                // here is the problem... how can I call buildTable
                $this.buildTable(data);

                ... some code here
                I want to call also the init function on the top.
            }

            function buildTable(data) {

                $('#contactsContent').html(data);

            }   
            getData();
        })();
    });

})(document, window, jQuery);
```

Inside **Employee** main function I have a problem calling inside `getData()` the function `buildTable()` and also after that I want to call the `init()` function on the top.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getData()` and `buildTable()` are sibling functions to each other and therefore, they are in the same scope. There is no need to prefix the call with `$this`.

Just use:  `buildTable(data);`

I must also say that you seem to have a lot of unnecessary function wrappers, which, when removed, make calling `init()` straight-forward as well.

It also looks like you want to call `init()` twice. Is that right?

Lastly, if you really do only have the code you're showing here, there is no need to wrap all of the code with your outermost function as the JQuery `document.ready` function will execute as soon as the DOM is ready.

Here's a rewritten version of your code:

```js
$(function() {
 'use strict';
   
  var Site = window.Site;
  Site.run();

  // Init function
  (function init() {              
    $('tr[data-toggle="slidePanel"]').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var me = $(this);
       //.... some code here
    }
  })();
        
  // Employee function
  //... some code here
    
  buildTable(data);
    
  //... some code here
  init();
    
  function buildTable(data) {
    $('#contactsContent').html(data);    
  }   
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @VAAA I see no reason to be using `$this` at all. You have a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: "All the functions that you need to work with are in visible scopes to each other." Nope, init is in a different scope, take another look at the code in the question.

Comment: @LajosArpad True, but if you look at my answer, you'll see that I've removed the unnecessary wrapper.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I agree with you, but the statement is still inaccurate. This statement prevented me from upvoting your answer...

Comment: @LajosArpad Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want with minimalistic changes, you can do the following:

Change

```
function init() {
```

to

```
window.init = function() {
```

and then call it with `window.init()` whenever you need it. This will be a global variable and will be reachable from any scope. If this is against your intention, then do not choose this solution. You need to do this since `init` is in a different scope from where you intend to use it. On the other hand, you can call `buildTable` as it is.

In general, you can call a function from a scope if the function is in the scope or is in one of the ancestor scopes.

Comment: Why in the world would you recommend making `init()` an explicit global property? That is an absolute "no-no".

Comment: @ScottMarcus I intend to give the op a solution which is as close as possible to his/her code in question. You have given another solution which involved complete refactoring. That's an option too. There are many options, and when we call an option a "no-no", we need to show our arguments in support of our statement.

Comment: It's quite universal that global variables are not a good thing. Suggesting that with *"You **need** to do this..."* (when you absolutely don't) and no explanation of what this is or why it solves the problem or the many reasons why you wouldn't want to do this is not a great solution.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you are right when you state that we need to explain it, I will do that. However, when you state that "global variables are not a good thing" you are not giving an argument. You are giving your opinion without foundation. In fact you can use globals without a problem, when you avoid globals, you need to have your reason. Such a reason might be to avoid naming confusion or to keep some inner variables "private". So there are valid scenarios when globals are not a good thing, but let's not make a religion of this.

Comment: @ScottMarcus since you were right that there was not enough explanation, I have added some explanation to make sure there will be no misunderstandings and the op will have a chance to avoid this solution if in his/her scenario using globals is not an option.

Comment: Avoiding global scope is not my opinion - - it's a tried and true best practice, not just in JavaScript, but in absolutely every programming language. This is a computer science issue, not a specific programming language issue. And, while it's true that I haven't listed the myriad of reasons why you shouldn't do it, it's mostly because, in my 20+ years of experience, I find that it's quite understood. Are there exceptions and times when a global is warranted? Yes, but those times are few and far between. In JavaScript, those times are for when you are creating a global namespace to work in.

Comment: @ScottMarcus my approach is to think instead of to believe. I did not start programming yesterday either, but I consider that irrelevant, just as the amount of experience you have when we are debating an issue. In my opinion relevant is that you think that we should avoid globals and I think that we should think. I am against mechanic rules. We are beings able to think, not robots. Globals are possible, therefore they are an option. If you have a problem with globals in general, then share your arguments, not your SO points or experience years.

Comment: If I believe something because I've thought about it, is that OK? If I tell you that oxygen is important for breathing, do you really need for me to explain why? Since it was you that expressed that you **need** to do it with globals,it is incumbent upon you to explain why. Also, `eval()` and `==` are possible in JavaScript as well, but both should also be avoided. `possible !== good`. Lastly, I did not mention anything about SO points, I only related my experience. How about if I leave it like this... What would be wrong with this line of code: `window.close = function(){alert('Hello!');};`

Comment: @ScottMarcus there can be several solutions to a problem, you probably know that as well. I did not claim that my solution was the only possible solution, so the word "need" implied that it is a dependency for the practical application of this answer. It is not like the invalid sentence in your initial answer, which was provably false. Globals can be used, period. If you have a problem with them, then you need to show us what will be the problem with them in this specific case.

Comment: @ScottMarcus of course you did not mention anything about SO points, because you have less points than me. You have mentioned the number of years you have been programming,because you assumed that you started it earlier and therefore you assumed further that I will believe you that globals are bad, because you have 20+ years of experience. Science does not work that way.

Comment: Your last comment makes several incorrect assumptions, period. My last comment did show what the problem is with globals and your statement is false, because you do not **need** to do this. My answer too, was misleading and I adjusted it

Comment: @ScottMarcus "You need to do this since init is in a different scope from where you intend to use it." This is the sentence you are referring to. The sentence has the fact that init is in a different scope as its premise. In that case you need to have access to that variable indeed, therefore my statement is valid. If you refactor the code, then this is no longer needed.

Comment: Frankly, I find it unbelievable that you are pushing back on any of this. For someone with your rep and experience, it's rather astonishing that you would provide such a reckless anti-pattern of an answer, nor would you recognize how your statement could easily be misunderstood. Anyway, good luck in your travels.

Comment: @ScottMarcus your "argument" about the 20+ years experience you have is a logical fallacy, the appeal to authority, or argumentum ad verecundiam in Latin. I am not assuming anything. Your penultimate comment did not show what is wrong with globals in this specific case. You are reverting the onus of proof.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I stated that window.init is needed since init is in a different scope. Since it is in a different scope, without refactoring you need to either set it to global or use some very ugly hack. This is why it is needed. If the code is refactored, then this is no longer needed. You stated that globals should not be used. I asked for a reason and still did not get any reasonable arguments from you in support of your statement. With all due respect, I am not convinced by your arguments, therefore I wish you all the best, until next time.